# Knex whereExists query with jsonb_array_elements

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, knex.js

I have query on postgres like this and that working well

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(column1) AS elem
  WHERE elem::jsonb ? 'answer'
) AND column2 IS NOT NULL;
```

here is some my query what I was try

```js
  const data = await knex('table_name')
    .select('*')
    .whereNotNull('column2')
    .where(knex.raw(`jsonb_array_elements(column1) AS elem`))
    .whereRaw('elem WHERE elem::jsonb ? answer')
    .returning('*');

// or

  const data = await knex('table_name').whereExists(function () {
    this.select(knex.raw('1'))
      .from(knex.raw('jsonb_array_elements(column1) AS elem'))
      .whereRaw('elem::jsonb ? \'answer\'');
  });
```

I expect to got all row with row data on column1 (type of jsonb) without have variable answer,
but I was try a lot and got confuse to implement that on knex, I try using raw on all that's query but it's not work, help me

Answer (score 0):

Then I was try and got something like this

```
  const data = await knex('table_name')
    .whereNotNull('column2')
    .whereNotExists(function () {
      this.select('*')
        .from(knex.raw('jsonb_array_elements(table_name.column1) AS elem'))
        .whereRaw("elem->>'answer' IS NOT NULL OR elem->'answer' IS NOT NULL");
    });
```

I hope someone here but's it's fine, hopefully this help you